# next js нужно расписать типы для поля

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nextjs

я прохожу по инпутам и собираю их в массив, чтобы получить их id, очень мудреный способ, код такой

```
  const getErrorIds = () => {
    let errorIds = [];
    if (clonesErrors) {
      errorIds = Object?.values(clonesErrors).map(
        (er: object) => console.log('err type: ', typeof er, 'er: ', er)
      );
    }
    return errorIds;
  };
```

нужно задать тип для er, any не канает, object, как я думаю тоже не то,
когда я выывожу er на консоль, я получаю такой объект

```
{
  clone_name: {
    type: 'required',
    message: '',
    ref: {accessKey: '', value, aling: '', alt: ''...}
  }
}
```

в поле ref куча всяких свойств, как я понимаю это как раз инпут, можете подсказать какой правильно тип указать для er, либо я могу его расписать сам
как-то так

```
  interface erProps {
    clone_name: {
      message: string;
      ref:
      type: string;
    };
  }
```

но, что писать в поле ref я не знаю, что-то вроде element, как мне кажется, но точно я не знаю

Comment: крч я сделаль вот так, кидайте тапками если что
export type erProps = {
  clone_name: {
    message: string;
    ref: HTMLInputElement;
    type: string;
  };
};